# Count managers without sales

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 tables:

1. Sales (date, manager_id)
2. Manager (manager_id, employment_date)
3. Calendar (date)

I need to calculate distinct count of managers without sales on a certain date. I tried this approach:

```
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Manager[manager_id]),
    FILTER(
        Manager,
        EXCEPT(
            VALUES(Manager[manager_id]),
            VALUES(Sales[manager_id])
        )
    )
)
```

but it didn't work.

Question 1: What do I need to fix to make it work or maybe there is a better logic?

Question 2: How to add a condition to count only managers who's been already employed on that date?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you update your question to describe exactly how it didn't work? What error message(s) did you see, and what did you expect to see? [Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the Calendar table has a relationship with the Sales table on date.

Q1
You can create 3 measures:

```
Managers= COUNT(Manager[manager_id])

Managers with sales = DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[manager_id])

Managers without sales = [Managers] - [Managers with sales]
```

Or put it all into one measure:

```
Managers without sales= 
VAR managers = COUNT(Manager[manager_id])
VAR managersWithSales = DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[manager_id])
RETURN managers - managersWithSales
```

Q2:
To do that, you need to get the selected date and then pass it as a filter:

```
EmployedManagersWithoutSales =
VAR selectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[date])
VAR managers = CALCULATE(COUNT(Manager[manager_id]), Manager[employment_date] <= selectedDate )
VAR managersWithSales = DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[manager_id])
RETURN managers - managersWithSales
```